# R Shiny: UI Element to navigate over a custom vector of numbers

Tags: r, user-interface, vector, shiny, numbers

I wanted to ask if there is any possibility to display a vector of numbers within a UI element, which allows you to pick only the numbers from the vector?

For example an extended numericInput, which only allows you to select the numbers which are given. 
For instance, we have a vector which is defined as:

```
vec <- c(1, 2, 5, 7, 10)
```

So when I navigate through it, it should only allow me to select one of the numbers above. I know I could use a `selectInput`, but this doesn't suit the requirements.

Is there any possibility I could make a `numericInput` work like this? Or is there even a better solution?

Comment: Why do you say that a `selectInput` doesn't suit the requirements?

Comment: I need this to run through plots, which are generated from data and this data is numbered from for example 1 to 50000. When you navigate through the numericInput it is all fine, but then there is an option, where you can upload a file with numbers which are special. Let's say number 5555 and 7777 are special. Then I want a numericInput, where I can only select 5555 and 7777 and navigate with the arrow keys. The problem with selectInput is, that you navigate through 1 to 150000 and with an selectInput this can't be displayed correcly.

Answer (score 1):

The R package `shinyWidgets` provides a mixture of `sliderInput` and `radioButtions`: A fixed set (vector) of choices to choose between based on a slider.

```
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    sliderTextInput(inputId = "Id", label = "Choose a value:", 
                    choices = c(1, 2, 5, 7, 10), grid = TRUE)
  ),
  function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

For more examples see `shinyWidgets::shinyWidgetsGallery()`